# Is there an easy and fast way to generate JavaScript?

Tags: python, ajax, web-crawler, scrapy

My problem begins when i try to crawl an app store, lets say google play.
for every app there are alot of comments and i want to crawl them FAST.
but the comment section in google is generated by java script.
here is a link for example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftAMHM in that link you can see that in order to generate more comments you need to click on a button several times. (after 5-6 clicks aprox) the page generate more comments by executing a javascript.

At first i solved this problem using a web driver (firefox) and simulate a real person clicking on the button, and it generate comments, and he keep pressing till all comments are generated.

Problem with this is: 1, it takes too much time. 2, sometimes after tons fo clicks and JS generation the web browser is fail to response.

What I need is a way to generate all comments per application in a better, faster way. maybe theres some kind of tech, or just anything else that would improve my solution,

Im using a spider I've created in scrapy.

All kind of help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons they generate/show additional comments is exactly that they do not want someone to crawl them... the other is for the initial page to load without them (faster), and only if someone starts reading comments to show few more..

Unless they provide an API where you can pull all the comments at once, I do not see another quick way of pulling them, apart of simulating clicks and scrolls... (slow way of doing it)

Answer (score 0):

Are you respecting [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)?  Why or why not?

Comment: if you refering to play.google.com/robots.txt -> Disallow: /apps, its just easy to test this ability on an app there. i try to develop this feature right now, regardless of robots.txt (so right now, i dont address this).